# Running a LAPACK build on different processors

Tags: c++, intel, lapack, blas, intel-mkl

If I build LAPACK on Windows / VS2010 using an Intel processor, will I be able to run the compiled code on another processor? I ask this, because I see that there are different instructions for compiling LAPACK on Intel or non-Intel processors.

I am thinking of using LAPACK as part of my project. I was going to build my project on my computer which has an Intel processor and then take the executable and simply run it on any other PC, regardless of the type of the processor it has. I have already considered using packages such as Eigen or MKL; but MKL is not cheap and Eigen was not fast enough for my application, so I decided to go with LAPACK / LAPACKE.